# If a power supply is not grounded, what situations could cause electrocution?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, switch-mode-power-supply, mains, grounding

I have a 24V power supply on one of my machines that was not properly grounded from the manufacturer. A loose screw on the board was causing this, but even after that was corrected, other factors resulted in a high resistance reading (6 ohms) from the chassis.

I've since replaced the unit for my own safety, but am curious what types of situations could have caused danger from this? I realize mains voltage can kill me, but I can't figure out how that situation would even occur.

This question is simply for the sake of learning, so any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: What initially made you suspicious that something was wrong somewhere i.e.what were the symptoms initially?

Comment: @Andyaka I haven't had any issues, but a lot of people with the same 3D Printer were reporting getting shocked when touching the metal printer frame. Several others responded, mentioning these power supplies are poorly grounded, or not grounded at all, as was my case.

On a similar but different note, a few also noticed the power cable itself wasn't grounded either. Someone on Youtube cut one open and the ground wire didn't even run from end to end. I know jack about electricity so I just upgraded to a UL rated unit and ordered a new power cable.

Comment: Also: *"reading (6 ohms) from the chassis"* From the chassis to where?

Comment: @Oldfart The ground terminal on the power the supply

Comment: Do you have RCDs (GFCIs in America) on your power distribution system?

Comment: They aren't on my outlets, not sure past that.

Comment: At least provide PSU model and make and preferably a link to datasheet. But the fact is that if the PSU has an earth/ground pin, it must have proper wiring and proper mains plug and connected to a earthed/grounded mains socket, or you can experience the tingling or shocks because the power supply mains input EMI filter needs to be grounded or the metal case floats at half mains supply via filter caps. It can even damage devices when for example connecting a data cable between two devices.

Comment: @Justme Here is the model (sompom s-360-24), although it's a cheap unit from China, can't find much else on it https://www.sunsky-online.com/product/default!view.do?subject.itemNo=S-RSP-0111D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear for me which ground was missing from your device:

- if it is the PE connection that is failing, I would say only a short between the housing and the mains line (caused by loose cable, screw inside the housing, etc.) would cause danger
- if you meant the power ground, it should not cause any dangers, unless the unconnected negative side of the primer transformer gets shorted to the housing

Update to the first point: please consider the comment of Justme:

> you can experience the tingling or shocks because the power supply
>   mains input EMI filter needs to be grounded or the metal case floats
>   at half mains supply via filter caps

Comment: Not sure if I can link Youtube here but this short video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAZKu8e1-S8) shows someone with the same issue. I just tested the same way that he did and decided to replace it, but was curious in what situations that ungrounded/poorly grounded mains power could actually hurt/kill someone.